# Windows 8 does not recognize DVD drive

Tags: windows-8, hyper-v, device-manager, disk-management

I have recently installed Windows 8 Enterprise edition on my Lenovo Z580 laptop. After I have mounted an ISO image to install Visual Studio 2012 by Hyper-V, my DVD-drive disappeared.

I unmounted and rejected the ISO afterwards and even stopped Hyper-V service.
It's not shown in *My Computer* or *Disk Management* or *Device Manager*.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to run this command from a command prompt with [admin rights](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token):

```
reg.exe add "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\atapi\Controller0" /f /v EnumDevice1 /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000001
```

Now reboot and see if this fixes it.

Comment: yes problem solved thank you a lot. can you more explain what just happened please? thank you again

Comment: by default Win8 only enums IDE devices with are configure as master. This also adds the enum of slave devices.